# after formatting iis throws 401.2 on anonymous access

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have a developer environment with two sites configured with anonymous access.  Everything was working fine until I migrated to a VM.  Now each time I try to enter I get a 401.2 error. I've searched all over the place and tried fixes from various MS knowledgebases but I can't get past the message. If I enable basic authentication it works but I need it to work without authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that our app was nested inside another app, after changing the virtual location for the app, the problem went away

Comment: This should be an edit to the original Question.  Serverfault isn't a traditional forum, Read our FAQ. http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: @TomO'Connor Actually, no. Since this is a resolution to the problem, it is perfectly acceptable for this to be an answer. And after the time limit has passed (48 hours I think) Nicolás can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the same issue just now and solved it by brute forcing some settings and for us enabling windows authentication with hard coded credentials (the machine's login) solved the problem. It's not really anonymous like we like it, but client (browser) side you won't be prompted.

Comment: sounds like fun... will try it

Comment: could you share what you did to get it working? I'm a bit lost on the matter :S